# Store data in selenium webdriver

Tags: maven, selenium, jenkins, webdriver

Im looking for a way to store data in selenium for use in future tests.
Im using jenkins, maven + selenium and testng.

How can i store some data, lets say i want to run test, get some data from website (weather forecast). Store it somewhere and next day run test to check if forecast match todays weather.

I can store it in txt file, and parse by regex but im sure there is better way to do it?

Comment: Your question is quite broad, and might be down-voted or flagged for closing for this reason.

Answer (score 0):

You have to consider what "selenium webdriver" is in this context. It is a Java app. It "exists" only when it is running. Once the run stops, it is purged from memory, including all data it held. If you are using JUnit or TestNG (as you specified), then this data is purged even more frequently: after every the class.

To accomplish what you are asking, you will need something external to your tests. You can certainly utilize a txt file as you suggested. A spreadsheet might do for your purposes. Most applications utilize an entire database.

You also mentioned Jenkins. This will make the external storage a more interesting problem, as Jenkins often purges the current working directory before each run.